# Terraform Override AWS managed policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

My request seems simple and yet I can't realize it with Terraform.
I want to **create** a new **AWS Policy** based on `SecurityAudit` managed policy to which I want to add a condition

```
"Condition": {
   "StringNotEquals": {
      "aws:TagKeys/MyTag": "disabled"
   }
}
```

I tried to use `aws_iam_policy_document` feature and then attached my policy to my role

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "security-audit-policy-override" {
  statement {
    principals {
      type        = "Federated"
      identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/SecurityAudit"]
    }

    condition {
      test     = "StringNotEquals"
      values   = ["aws:TagKeys/MyTag"]
      variable = "disabled"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "security-audit-override" {
  policy     = data.aws_iam_policy_document.security-audit-policy-override.json
  role       = aws_iam_role.my_role.name
}
```

But I have the following mistake when I do a `terraform apply` command :

```
Error: Error putting IAM role policy terraform-XXXXXXXXX: MalformedPolicyDocument: Policy document should not specify a principal.
```

So, do you know how to override an existing managed AWS IAM Policy ?

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear why you can't do this?

Answer (score 4):

Theoretically, you can do this, but not with `SecurityAudit`. This is because this policy has **over 12000 characters**. But user managed policies are [limited to](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_iam-quotas.html#reference_iam-limits-entity-length) 6,144.

So you have to split `SecurityAudit` into two or three user managed policies yourself. The best way is to construct these policies manually, or trim `SecurityAudit` down significantly.